# Invoking Lambda in Codepipeline with Input artifacts being a file from Github from the source

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-codepipeline

As part of my AWS codepipeline, I have the first source stage which gets my branch. Inside the branch, I have a file called  `hello.txt` and a whole bunch of other files which I don't care about.

Is it possible to utilise and feed into the AWS Lambda Action Provider, the contents of the hello.txt.

If so, how?

I defined SourceArtifact define by Source as the input artifact. Now, how can I reference just that one file and it's value with python

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to put a codebuild project after the source action, read the file and then export the variables within the shell and then declare them in the buildspec.

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html#build-spec.env.exported-variables

```
version: 0.2

run-as: Linux-user-name

env:
  shell: shell-tag
  variables:
    key: "value"
    key: "value"
  parameter-store:
    key: "value"
    key: "value"
  exported-variables:
    - variable
    - variable
```

Within your pipeline, set a **Namespace** for the CodeBuild Action and input the output of the source stage.

```
 - Name: GetVars
   Actions:
   - ActionTypeId:
     Category: Build
     Owner: AWS
     Provider: CodeBuild
     Version: "1"
     Configuration:
        ProjectName: !Ref BuildProject
        InputArtifacts:
          - Name: !Ref SourceArtifactName
     Name: Build
    Namespace: ProjectVars
    RunOrder: 1
```

Then you can pass them like this:

```
     Category: "Invoke"
     Owner: AWS
     Provider: Lambda
       Version: "1"
       Configuration:
       FunctionName: !Ref FunctionName
       UserParameters: !Sub "{\"VAR1\":\"#{ProjectVars.VAR1}\",\"var2\":\"#{ProjectVars.VAR2}\"}"
       Name: RunLambda
        RunOrder: 2
```

It's a bit messy escaping the Parameter object but the above worked for me. In your case you would have to read the whole file and pass it as a string and unpack it via the Lambda.

Answer (score 0):

If you want access to a file in a lambda function that is called from the pipeline you can pass in the artifact that contains that file as an `InputArtifact`. Within the lambda you can access information about that artifact within the `event` ([Example JSON event](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/action-reference-Lambda.html#action-reference-Lambda-event)). You can then retrieve the object from the S3 bucket. You'll likely need to unzip the S3 file to get at the specific file you're looking for, but at that point the structure and file names will be what you specified in the source step of the pipeline.

Comment: Ya. That's the problem. I don't want to put it on S3 and zip it up because it is just another layer. It's just a .txt file with a bunch of data that I get with my first source step from Github that I want to feed the value into the Lambda which is my step 5.

Comment: Unzipping a file that is just a small text file isn’t much of a layer. The CodeBuild project is already zipping it. If you only want to unzip the single file you can make that file it’s own artifact in your CodeBuild project, and then also as a separate output artifact in the pipeline.